# How to use redux saga in editable table efficiently

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a multi page react application in which one endpoint has to show data in tabular form. Show I take `GET_INFO` action on `componentWillMount` of that endpoint. Now I have a reducer called `table_info` which has `table_data` array and `shouldTableUpdate` boolean in it.

My table is editable with `edit` and `delete` icon in every row. I am facing problem in `update`, on `update` I call reducer with action `UPDATE_TABLE_ROW` and if success than I do something like following :

```
//reducer.js

const initialState = {
    table_data:{}, shouldTableUpdate:false;
}
export default function myReducer(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case UPDATE_SUCCESS:
            // how to handle edited row here?
            // also when I print my state of this reducer
            // state becomes nested, so if one does lots of updates
            // it will be become very heavy... 
            return {...state, shouldTableUpdate:true}
    }
}
```

Can you tell how to handle update, delete, add on table using redux saga efficiently ? On googling I get naive examples only, so came to SO.

Note: Can't show the actual code as it's for my company project. Sorry for that.

Thanks.

Comment: update should be like if success show new data otherwise old data should be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell how to handle update, delete, add on table using redux saga efficiently ?

Well you can plainly manipulate the `state` object using a reducer only.

**Comments:**

1. `table_data` is a list and not an object.
2. I don't think you'll be needing `shouldTableUpdate` since state change in store will trigger a component update if state field is mapped in `mapStateToProps`.

So here's a basic template of adding, updating and deleting items via reducer.

```
const initialState = {
  table_data: [],
};

export default function myReducer(state=initialState, action){
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        table_data: [
          ...state.table_data,
          action.item, // item to be added
        ]
      };
    case UPDATE_ITEM: 
      let updatedItem = action.item;
      // do something with updatedItem
      return {
        ...state,
        table_data: table_data.map(e => (
          e.id === updatedItem.id ? updatedItem : e
        )),
      };
    case DELETE_ITEM:
      const index = state.table_data.findIndex(e => e.id === action.item.id);
      const numItems = state.table_data.length;
      return {
        ...state,
        table_data: [
          // exclude index
          ...table_data.slice(0, index),
          ...table_data.slice(index+1, numItems),
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: that's what i did, thanks :) btw I have saga like "function* addNewRow({param})" now inside this I call axios.post to post new data to DB and on success not able to "yield" which is inside ".then(result =>{ ... })"